# From keyword not found where expected

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio C# 2005 and Oracle for my database. I have a block of code with SQL Statment.

Here is the code:

```
 con = new OracleConnection(conStr);
            con.Open();
 query = " SELECT EQPID, " + 
                    " DECODE(CUTOFF_DATE, '20120501', SUM(TKINQTY))'20120501', " +
 " DECODE(CUTOFF_DATE, '20120502', SUM(TKINQTY))'20120502', " + 
                    " DECODE(CUTOFF_DATE, '20120503', SUM(TKINQTY))'20120503'  " +
                    " FROM DAILY_DATA " +
                    " WHERE CUTOFF_DATE BETWEEN '20120501' AND '20120503' " +
                    " AND EQPID LIKE 'MS-%' " +
                    " GROUP BY CUTOFF_DATE, EQPID " +
                    " ORDER BY CUTOFF_DATE, EQPID";
 da = new OracleDataAdapter();
 da.SelectCommand = new OracleCommand(query, con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            table.DataSource = dt;
 con.Close();
```

As I try to debug the it, I keep on having the error message of :

From keyword not found where expected

But as I tried it on oracle, it run without any error.

THANKS A LOT. =)

Comment: Your query syntax is invalid, and won't run in Oracle directly either. Simply copy the SQL portion, paste it into a SQL utility, remove all of the double quotes and plus signs, and try and run it. It's invalid. (Hint: Look right after the two `SUM` statements; that portion is incorrect in both uses.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to name the columns of your result `20120501`, `20120502`, and `20120503`, you are using single quotes instead of double quotes. Change your query to

```
SELECT EQPID, " + 
" DECODE(CUTOFF_DATE, '20120501', SUM(TKINQTY))\"20120501\", " +
" DECODE(CUTOFF_DATE, '20120502', SUM(TKINQTY))\"20120502\", +...
--                                             ^^        ^^
```

to fix the problem. Note that since the query string is inside a C# string, double quotes need to be escaped with a backslash.

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight. =)